# Make edge data set from a specific data.frame without for-loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame present information for an directed graph:

```
  point connectTo
1     A      B, C
2     B      A, C
3     D
```

Column "point" let us know all points in the graph.
Each element of column "connectTo" is a list contains all point that point (in column "point") connect to.

How can I make an edge data frame like this:

```
 source destination
1      A      B
2      A      C
3      B      C
4      B      A
```

The graph is rather big (with ~400,000 node and ~ 3000,000 edge) ;therefore, a solution without for-loop would be nice.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: 
Class of "connectTo" is list. Below is code to make an sample data frame:

```
point <- c("A","B","D")
connectTo <- list(list("B","C"),list("A","C"),list())
test <- data.frame(point, I(connectTo))
```

Comment: In your first data frame, the column "connect to" is a string (the nodes names being separated by a coma), or something else?

Comment: Class of "connectTo" is list. Below is code to make an sample data frame:
 
`point <- c("A","B","D")`

`connectTo <- list(list("B","C"),list("A","C"),list())`

`test <- data.frame(point, I(connectTo))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but that should do it:

```
tmp <- apply(test,1,function(x){pt <- x$point[1];return(Reduce(rbind,lapply(x$connectTo,function(y){print(y);return(matrix(ncol=2,c(pt,y)))})))})
final_matrix = Reduce(rbind, tmp)
```

Comment: The code worked fine in small data but with it took long for a big data frame. It looks like R is not suitable for task like this (the original data frame read from json file and reading process was also too slow too).

Thank you for help.

Comment: @DuyThọNguyễn  Maybe you need to process the data outside of R? My suggestion would be to try mongodb since you say that your original data are in json. Might be faster and the code will be cleaner that what I wrote... good luck!